# Marketing Cloud Connect features in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, marketing-cloud-connect

I'd like to know if now it's possible to use Marketing Cloud Connect features in Lightning Experience?
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Help Article: Connect the Clouds with Marketing Cloud Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_connect_the_clouds.htm&type=5) states - it's not currently possible:

> Lightning Experience is not supported for Marketing Cloud Connect features.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I'm very new at it and I'm trying to understand better how it works. So I install and configure marketing cloud connect in Classic but then I'd like to know if in lightning experience I can see some data, for instance Engagement tracking data or data event? Is this possible? thank you

Comment: @Chris I'm not that proficient in MC sadly and I'm afraid I won't be able to help you here. But I hope someone will give you more insight on that topic.